# yum list installed | wc -l Vs. rpm -qa | wc -l

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

This goes back to very basics, however I am confused on how.

We know `yum` is a repository manager that is based on `rpm` the package manager in RPM based systems, like Fedora.

Having said that, I thought these two commands can be used to produce the same output (in that sense I guess yum commands are the wrapper for rpm commands), however I was just proved to be wrong. Please consider the following example:

```
[myuser@localhost ~] yum list installed | wc -l
1627 

[myuser@localhost ~] rpm -qa | wc -l
1640
```

These two commands produce different result, that I believed should not. I would be grateful if anyone can explain the scenario behind it.

PS: I am on Fedora 28

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: duplicate with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/different-list-of-installed-packages-reported-by-rpm-compared-to-yum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they don't produce exactly the same output... `yum list installed` also prints some headers:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
epel
Installed Packages
```

furthermore some packages can be printed on multiple lines with their version number and repository.

If you start counting those lines, then the count won't be correct. Note that the output of `yum list installed` also reprints output on the same line; not sure how `wc` deals with that...

The count of `rpm -qa | wc -l` however is biased also; because it contains the **pubkey** entries; which are not real packages.

Take a look at this answer where there are many details on these outputs: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330599/64031

Comment: Even though there are no headers, not everything output by `rpm -qa` is a package.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: do you have any example of that please?

Comment: Everything with the name `gpg-pubkey` is a public key for package signing.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Thank you for the input, however I just checked the outputs only there is 1 header line in `yum list installed`

Comment: oh right, I forgot about that, but that doesn't change anything to the answer; because `yum list installed` would show those as well

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for the input, however the problem here is `rpm -qa | ws -l` shows a lower figure than the other command

Comment: No, it doesn't, and in fact can't.

Comment: @Musa run your command again with piping the output; more lines will show up... they don't show when you do `yum list installed | less` (strangely...)

Comment: @Musa: That's not what the question body says.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, you are right, but when you said public keys would also appear in the output, I assumed that they will not be in the output of the other command, so `rpm -qa` should have larger number of lines in output since it contains the public keys extra to the other command. Sorry for the confusion at first place

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is right; and to as he suspected; the pubkeys show up with `rpm -qa` but not with `yum list installed`

Comment: here is a complete answer to your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330599/64031

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you are right about the keys, I made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @Musa: I have updated my answer as requested.